# How I can get related "projects" beans from account bean? SugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

How can I find the Projects records related to an Account using the SugarCRM SugarBean object (i.e. using the PHP objects instead of using the database directly)?

For related contacts I use:

```
if ($accaunt->load_relationship('contacts'))
{
    $relatedBeans = $account->contacts->getBeans();
}
```

I want something like this:

```
$relatedBeans = $account->projects->getBeans();
```

I have the same problem with Campaigns and Members (related child Accounts).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Since when does PHP use beans?

Comment: @developerwjk I mean sugarBean of SugarCRM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much there.

```
<?php
// Assuming $account is a loaded SugarCRM Account record
$account->load_relationship('project');
$projects = $account->project->getBeans();
foreach($projects as $project){
    var_dump($project->name);
}
```

Replace 'project' with 'campaigns' or 'members' or any other module to find more. You can find the names of these links in `/modules/Accounts/vardefs.php`. It works the same with any custom relationships you create, but those will be listed in `/custom/modules/Accounts/vardefs.php` since they're custom to your instance.

Also, if you're loading more than one relationship in your script, you can load all relationships at once instead of doing each one individually:

```
<?php
$account->load_relationships();
```

Also, fuller documentation is available in the [SugarCRM Developer Documentation on SugarBean -> Fetching Relationships](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.7/02_Application_Framework/SugarBean/01_Fetching_Relationships/).

Answer (score 1):

This example will deal with grabbing **related contacts to an account**. Let’s take a look at the code

```
$account = new Account(); 
$account->retrieve($_REQUEST['record']); 
$contacts = $account->get_linked_beans('contacts','Contact'); 

foreach ( $contacts as $contact ) { 
echo "{$contact->name}\n" 
}
```